# Vim - searching within braces

Tags: search, vim

In vim is it possible to limit searching ONLY within closing braces?

For example.

```
int main() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    for (...) {
        <><>
        <><>
    }
return 0;
}
```

Therefore for a search in the `...` lines should search the entire code.
However, a search in the `<><>` lines should only search within the for loop.

Answer (score 8):

First do the selection with `vi{`. Then press `Esc` to discard it. Then press `/` key to start searching. Prepend your search pattern with `\%V` to restrict the scope of search to previously selected visual block.

Sources:

- `i{` is a text object of *inner brace block*. Here's a [nice tutorial on text objects](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/).
- and here's [more about search & replace in visual selection](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vi{` to select text inside the braces before searching from the visual mode.